# Changes to string still in effect after loop ends in Java

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, while-loop

So I have this script:

```
class input {
public static void main (String[] args){
    String hexa;
    hexa = "68101005200B10034D201A10162014100D17060520100F06200E101306200409020D0D060F0806200A0F201A101613200B1016130F061A4F2075090A1420100F06201802142007020A130D1A200602141A20151020041302040C4F207802140F4815200A156020525359200C061A14200A1420022012160A150620140E020D0D200C061A14110204064D201410200A1520140910160D050F481520090217062015020C060F201A101620151010200D100F0820151020050604131A11152015090A14200E0614140208064F2078060D0D2005100F064D201A1016132014100D16150A100F200A14200F050311030210130A0D10074F";
    int pituus;
    pituus = hexa.length();
    int i = 1;
    char luku;
    char luku2;
    int asc;
    String pari;
    String koodi;
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder ASCII = new StringBuilder();
    for(int a = 0;a <30;a++){
    if (a > 0){
        hexa = sb.toString();
    }while(i < pituus){
    luku = hexa.charAt(i);
    luku2 = hexa.charAt (i-1);
    luku++;
           if(luku == 'G'){ 
        luku = '0';
        luku2++;
    }
           else if(luku == ':')
               luku = 'A';

    if (luku2 == '8')
        luku2 = '0';
 sb2.append(luku2);
 sb2.append(luku);
 pari = sb2.toString();
 sb2.setLength(0);
 asc = Integer.parseInt(pari,16);
 ASCII.append((char)asc);
 sb.append(luku2);
 sb.append(luku);
 i+=2;
    }
    koodi = ASCII.toString();
    System.out.printf("All hex pair values increased by: %d\n%s\n======================\n%s\n",a+1,hexa,koodi);
    }
}
}
```

EDIT2: Now on this version hexa is right before program steps, to while-loop. Inside while loop, program uses old value of hexa. Why is that and how to "update" the while-loop?

Comment: Debugger is your best option.

Comment: Could you be little more specific?

Comment: Use the debugger and you'll find your problem, it's the best tool for learning and finding bugs in your program.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive? what value does hexa contain?

Comment: Hexa is 490 char long string that contains values 0-9 and A-F, so it's hexdecimal string. The script increses every pair of the characters by 1 and turns the string to text. I try to loop it to give on the next step incrreasement by 2 next 3 and so on until increasement of 30. So if the hexa would be 686A it would print "ik" on first step "jl" next and so on.

Comment: The real problem is still unsolved.

Comment: When asking for help (and generally in programming) it is useful to stick with English names for variables. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553082/do-you-code-variables-in-your-language and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/do-people-in-non-english-speaking-countries-code-in-english

Comment: I don't think the names of variables to be relevant to my problem here. I would like to get back to the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the inner loop never is executed.

Because initially `pituus` is `0` and the inner loop isn't executed and `sb.toString();` is `""` and `pituus` is `0` again, because of this the inner loop never is executed.

Comment: Oh thats not a problem, Hexa is actually 490 characters long, I didn't include it due to it's lenght

Comment: I thnk the inner loop only is executed once.  And you repeat the other  29 times this statements:
     hexa = sb.toString();
     koodi = ASCII.toString();
     System.out.print(koodi);
This is because you don't update the value of i and pituus when you exit the loop

Comment: I updated the code a bit to make it more selfexplaining. The output is only too long put in comment.

Comment: Yeah you were right! Now I was able to solve my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Step through the program by hand or in a debugger. You'll find that `pituus` is first set to 0 and is never changed, so the inner `while`-loop is never entered.

Comment: I now included actual value of hexa.

Answer (score 0):

I have just ran your code (JDK 1.7.0_21) and the value of the hexa variable was indeed changed at the end of the main method:

```
hexa = "69111106210C11044E211B11172115110E18070621111007210F11140721050A030E0E07100907210B10211B111714210C11171410071B5021760A0B1521111007211903152108030B140E1B210703151B21161121051403050D5021790315104916210B16612153545A210D071B15210B1521032113170B160721150F030E0E210D071B15120305074E211511210B1621150A11170E06104916210A0318072116030D0710211B111721161111210E11100921161121060705141B121621160A0B15210F071515030907502179070E0E21061110074E211B1117142115110E17160B1110210B152110060412040311140B0E110850"
```

Please try to run the code yourself and give a detailed report of the expected and actual results.

P.S.
To be able to see the value of hexa at the end of the main method consider putting a non-modifying method call there:

```
            [...]
            koodi = ASCII.toString();
            System.out.print(koodi);
        }
        hexa.hashCode(); // place breakpoint here to see that the value has changed
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats true. But I want i to give me strings like this: 6911, 6A12, 6B13, 6C14... . Right now it only gives: 6911, 6911, 6911...

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the logic that would create those string(s?) As the question now stands, it is answered, the variable IS altered when the loop exits. If you still have problems with your code, try to make it clear what the code is for and how it tries to achieve that, using comments and descriptive variable names.

Comment: It is to decipher a message. Every pair of character represent a ascii code 0-127, but every pair of the characters are increased or decreased certain amount. So I made this script to make increasements 1-30 and then print representing ASCII characters.

Comment: So increasement by 1 is the value of hexa you posted on your comment, 6911110621... , but the problem is that every time for loop goes back up hexa regains its original value, so the recursion doesnt happen, it only gives same value 30 times. Hope I made myself clear this time. :D There might be easier ways, but I like to learn some programming at the same time.